# Using 'nestjs/jwt' signing with dynamic/user-related secret

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jwt, nestjs

I'm trying to create a user token based on the secret of the user trying to log in. However instead of using a secret from the environment I want to use a secret assigned to a user object inside the database.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { UserService } from '@src/modules/user/services';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  public constructor(private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
                     private readonly userService: UserService) {}

  public async createToken(email: string): Promise<JwtReply> {
    const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24;
    const user = await this.userService.user({ where: { email } });
    const accessToken = await this.jwtService.signAsync({ email: user.email },
                                                        /* user.secret ,*/
                                                        { expiresIn });

    return {
      accessToken,
      expiresIn,
    };
  }
}
```

I'm new to Nestjs and maybe I'm missing something. 
[node-jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#jwtsignpayload-secretorprivatekey-options-callback) does provide the necessary parameter in the `sign(...)` function. `nestjs/jwt` is missing this parameter (see code). How would you solve it without using `node-jsonwebtoken` or maybe a more abstract question: does my way of handling user secret make sense here? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not yet possible solely with nest's `JwtModule` but you can easily implement the missing parts yourself.

## Live Demo

[image: Edit Nest Dynamic JWT Secrets]

You can create tokens by calling the following routes:

user1 (secret: '123'): https://yw7wz99zv1.sse.codesandbox.io/login/1

user2 (secret: '456'): https://yw7wz99zv1.sse.codesandbox.io/login/2

Then call the protected route `'/'` with your token and receive your user:

```bash
curl -X GET https://yw7wz99zv1.sse.codesandbox.io/ \
      -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiIxIiwiaWF0IjoxNTUzNjQwMjc5fQ.E5o3djesqWVHNGe-Hi3KODp0aTiQU9X_H3Murht1R5U'
```

---

## How does it work?

In the `AuthService` I'm just using the standard `jsonwebtoken` library to create the token. You can then call `createToken` from your login route:

```
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

export class AuthService {
  constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {}

  createToken(userId: string) {
    const user = this.userService.getUser(userId);
    return jwt.sign({ userId: user.userId }, user.secret, { expiresIn: 3600 });
  }

  // ...
}
```

In the `JwtStrategy` you use `secretOrKeyProvider` instead of `secretOrKey` which can asynchronously access the `UserService` to get the user secret dynamically:

```
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
    private readonly userService: UserService,
  ) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKeyProvider: (request, jwtToken, done) => {
        const decodedToken: any = jwt.decode(jwtToken);
        const user = this.userService.getUser(decodedToken.userId);
        done(null, user.secret);
      },
    });
  }

  // ...
}
```

Note that the options you pass to the `JwtModule` like `expiresIn` will not be used, instead directly pass your options in the `AuthService`. Import the `JwtModule` without any options:

```
JwtModule.register({})
```

## General

> Does my way of handling user secret make sense here?

This is hard to answer without knowing your exact requirements. I guess there are use cases for jwt with dynamic secrets but with it you are losing a great property of jwt: they are stateless. This means that your `AuthService` can issue a jwt token and some `ProductService` that requires authentication can just trust the jwt (it knows the secret) without making any calls to other services (i.e. `UserService` which has to query the database).

If user-related keys are not a hard requirement consider rotating the keys frequently instead by making use of jwt's `kid` property.

Comment: This is precisely what I ended up doing (no other choise with `nestjs/jwt`). Except that I store the token in the user itself instead of decoding the token for the purpose of invalidating the token (in `secretOrKeyProvider`). Thank you for the general explanation. The staleless token argument forces me to think about it some more. Good point.

Comment: Glad to hear. :) If it's not a hard requirement consider rotating the keys frequently instead by making use of jwt's kid property

Comment: This is a very good idea. Do you have any sources how this is used in practice I can look up? I assume this needs to be done with a `secretOrKeyProvider` to temporarily accept previously used secrets?

Comment: Yep, at least for the expiration time you have to accept old keys. I haven't implemented it myself so I can't really point to a good ressource, sorry

Comment: Thanks, no problem. This small hint might be enough already. I'll try to come up with an elegant solution. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

The option to add `secret` into JwtSignOptions has been added in `nestjs/jwt` version **7.1.0**.

With that, the example would be:

```
public async createToken(email: string): Promise<JwtReply> {
    const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24;
    const user = await this.userService.user({ where: { email } });
    const accessToken = await this.jwtService.signAsync(
        { email: user.email },
        { expiresIn,
          secret: user.secret,
        });

    return {
      accessToken,
      expiresIn,
    };
 }
```

Comment: Correct: https://github.com/nestjs/jwt/pull/336. You could do the same with `secretOrKeyProvider` that I contributed long time ago. Only difference is that it's not used for key management but solely for secrets handling.

Comment: Good clarification @TomSiwik. This got me wondering what would be the idiomatic way to define e.g. whether one wants to sign/verify with refresh token secret or access token secret if using the `secretOrKeyProvider` (in the use case of having different tokens). The `jwt.SignOptions` and `jwt.VerifyOptions` seem not to be for this purpose.

Comment: Good question that could probably deserve an answer rather than a comment. No idea. I'm using this on endpoints and the endpoint itself defines how to sign it `/refresh` vs `/verify`. You could probably get around it with a `sub` claim https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.2 . Again... no idea.

Answer (score 1):

I had also case to sign access and refresh tokens with different secret keys.
If u follow nestjs docs, u see JwtModule is registered with single config and token is signed without options (with default config). To use **jwtService** sign function with  options import JwtModule.register with empty object

```
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
@Module({
  imports: [JwtModule.register({})],
  providers: [],
  controllers: []
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

And making config file with different sign options

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiConfigService {
    constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {   
    }

    get accessTokenConfig(): any {
        return {
            secret: this.configService.get('JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY'),
            expiresIn: eval(this.configService.get('JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME'))
        }
    }
    get refreshTokenConfig(): any {
        return {
            secret: this.configService.get('JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY'),
            expiresIn: eval(this.configService.get('JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME'))
        }
    }
}
```

u may sign token with desired config

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    constructor(private jwtService: JwtService, private apiConfigService: ApiConfigService ) {}

    login(user: any) {
            let payload = {username: user.username, id: user.id};
            let jwt = this.jwtService.sign(payload, this.apiConfigService.accessTokenConfig);
            //
            return { token: jwt };
        }
       
    }
```